# Wireshark doesn't filter correctly http.host

Tags: http, wireshark, host

When trying to filter for a specific host with `http.host=="abc.com"` it shows me everything instead of only the related packets.

What am I doing wrong?

Wireshark 1.12.6

Comment: Do you mean this does not work as a display filter (it should, assuming you are seeking precisely abc.com, and not a subdomain thereof), or as a capture filter (it doesn't, as far as I know) ?

Comment: If I use `==` is shows me other site as well, and the same happens with `contains`. Basically it shows me all the HTTP traffic that was captured.

Comment: You may want to upgrade to the newest version. You are a few versions behind.

Comment: @MassNerder Just updated to Wireshark 2 but the issue is still there.

Comment: I tried it on my workstation and it only picked up the packets to the specified domain. I did it without the quotes around the domain. Have you tried exporting the capture as a text file and searching through to see if the domain is in all the packets? File / Export Packet Dissection / As Plain Text File